# How to build Spring Native container in Google Cloud Build and use it in Cloud Run?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build, spring-native

I have a Kotlin application that I'd like to build into a native executable with Spring Native. Locally it works fine but I want it to be builded with Google Cloud Build and Docker and then use the created image in my Google Cloud Run step.

However I can't find any guide to make this happen? I have no idea what I need to setup in Google Cloud Build triggers to create a spring native application for Cloud Run.

Comment: Can you share what did you try and where you are stuck?

Comment: There are several steps that I recommend. First build your container locally and test it in Docker. Once that is running well and passing your QA tests, use the CLI (gcloud) and deploy to Cloud Run. Complete another round of tests. Then configure Cloud Build. Eidt your question and show your current work and the problem you have.